# How does pop() function works in python? It doesn't work in a way that I expect

Tags: python

I have these lines of codes in a class in python:

```
1        for i in range(len(self.rg_nodes_range)):
2            tmp_rg = self.rg_nodes_range
3            tmp_rg.pop(i)
```

The value for ***self***.**rg_nodes_range** is:

```
self.rg_nodes_range = [20, 21]
```

I expect that at the start of every loop, **tmp_rg** gets the value of *[20, 21]*, and then in line 3, drop the corresponding index *(i)* from **tmp_rg**. For example, I want **tmp_rg** to be *[21]* at the end of the first iteration *(when i==0)*, and to be *[20]*
at the end of the second iteration *(when i==1)*.

But it seems that it's not happening. I put some breakpoints and found out that in the first iteration, in line 3, **tmp_rg** and ***self*.rg_nodes_range** both change from *[20, 21]* to *[21]*. I double-checked it with these lines of code:

```
p = [1, 2, 3]
tp = p
tp.pop(0)
print(p)
print(tp)
```

and the output was (both **p** and **tp** changed):

```
[2, 3]
[2, 3]
```

Do you know what happens here? And how can I fix it to obtain my expected outputs?
Thank you.

Comment: `tmp_rg` and `self.rg_nodes_range` are two names for a single list - in Python, assignment *never* makes a copy of anything.  You'd need to write something like `tmp_rg = self.rg_nodes_range.copy()`.

Comment: You change the same object. Clone a list if you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a `pop()` problem. The function is working as expected what you need to look for is deep vs shallow copy concept as in python when you assign a variable to other, it simply creates a shallow copy thus modifying original will modify the copy as well. However if you create a deep copy it will clone the objects allowing you to modify them separately.

So this:

```
p = [1, 2, 3]
tp = p
tp.pop(0)
print(p)
print(tp)
```

produces:

```
[2, 3]
[2, 3]
```

However this:

```
p = [1, 2, 3]
tp = p.copy()
tp.pop(0)
print(p)
print(tp)
```

produces

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3]
```

Comment: Since this is a 1-dimensional list, the distinction between deep and shallow copy is irrelevant. `p.copy()` makes a shallow copy.

Comment: Seems more like a difference between a direct reference and a shallow copy. As @Barmar says above, `list.copy()` performs a shallow copy. You'd need `copy.deepcopy()` to get an actual deep copy, were that relevant